# Why does my Eclipse debugger fail to step into for the first time?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and learning to debug in Eclipse. I am getting an odd error in which the debugger fails to step into a function for the first time, but successfully does so the second time. Specifically, here are my steps.

1. Step over until I reach my desired function to examine.
2. Step into the function. Here is when I encounter the error "Source not found."
3. Step return. The debugger successfully returns to the previous stack frame above.
4. Step into the function once again. Strangely, step into works this time.

What could be awry? Why does it take two "step intos" to examine my desired function?

Comment: I can't remember why this happens atm, but I can assure you it's common :) Something with the build path I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when there are two statements on a line, and the inner statement is without source (such as a bare bones JRE).

```
myObject.myMethod(someObject.toString());
```

In this line, the first step-into, will step into the toString() Method on inner object (for which there may be no source available), the second step into will step into your own method (for which there will be code).

The way to resolve this (if it is happening for regular Java Runtime Classes) is to use a [full JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u32-downloads-1594644.html) for your project rather than a JRE and to follow good coding practise and move the inner statement into a variable so that each line does exactly one thing (the optimizer should ensure there is no performance penalty for doing this).

Answer (score 1):

f you have line like this:

```
func1(obj.func2());
```

the debugger first step into obj.func2()
if it's third party source or java src and you using jre, you might miss this source code and eclipse won't able to attach source for debuging (use maven! =)).

in the next 'step into' you will get to func1